# Which Visual Studio Code extensions add these options/icons to the sidebar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I saw on a [video presentation about TypeScript](https://mybuild.techcommunity.microsoft.com/sessions/77040?source=sessions) this icon in Visual Studio Code:

[image]

It looks like a git extension, but which extension is that? I would like to try it...

What about this other one?

[image]

It looks like they are useful extensions...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first view / icon is from the [GitLens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension.

The second view is actually built into VSCode. It shows "Find References" results, and consequently it only appears when Find References that has been executed in the current VSCode session.